# Plotting Interpolated 3D Data As A 2D Image using Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, scipy

The data set is made of a list `dfList` containing `pandas` `DataFrames`, each `DataFrame` consisting of the column `Y` and an identical `index` column. I am trying to plot all the DataFrames as a 2D plot with pixel color representing the `Y` values.

**Example of the Style of Plot Needed**

[image]

**Problem:** However, using `scipy.interpolate.griddata` with `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` produces a blank plot! What might be the problem?

I have added a link to the `pickle.dump` of `dfList` for reproducing the problem. Any help appreciated!!

**Matploblib Image**
[image]

**Code**

```
import scipy

# Meshgrid
xgrid = dfList[0].index.tolist()
ygrid = np.linspace(266, 1, 532)
Xgrid, Ygrid = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)

# Points
xo = dfList[0].index.tolist()
yo = [266, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 532]    # one for each DataFrame
points = [ [x, y] for y in yo for x in xo]
points = np.array(points)

# Values
values = []
for df in dfList:
    values.extend(df['Y'].real)
# values = [ item for item in df['Y'].real for df in dfList]    # faster way of collapsing list
values = np.array(values)

# Griddata
resampled = scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, (Xgrid, Ygrid), method='cubic')

plt.imshow(resampled.T, extent=[365,1099,266,532], origin='lower')
```

**`dfList`: Pickle Dump**

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/06076ecda9afcacfffd92b965996fe3e/raw/658e6157388ddedfe8882c2ad6c8f89af1eee5ac/dfList%2520(pickle%2520dump)

Comment: Is this problem really related to some pickled dataframe or can it [be reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using some mockup data?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I pickled the data `dfList` so it can be reproduced. The problem exists using the original data before pickling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To make this answer somehow useful for other people, find here first a general explanation. Below there is a more concrete solution to the question.*

#### The general explanation, `np.meshgrid` vs. `np.mgrid` in the use with `scipy.interpolate.griddata`.

I here provide an example which compares the use of `np.meshgrid` with `np.mgrid` when it comes to interpolation with `scipy.interpolate.griddata`. Gnerally speaking, the returns of `np.meshgrid` are the transposed returns of `np.mgrid` for the same grid.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# np. meshgrid
xgrid = np.arange(21)[::2]
ygrid = np.linspace(0,5,6)
Xgrid, Ygrid = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)

# np. mgrid
Xgrid2, Ygrid2 = np.mgrid[0:20:11j,0:5:6j]

# points for interpolation
points = np.random.rand(200, 2)
points[:,0] *= 20 
points[:,1] *= 5

# values
f = lambda x,y: np.sin(x)+ y
values = f(points[:,0], points[:,1])

# initerpolation using grid defined with np.meshgrid
resampled = scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, (Xgrid2, Ygrid2), method='cubic')

# interpolation using grid defined with np.mgrid
resampled2 = scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, (Xgrid.T, Ygrid.T), method='cubic')


fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1)
kws = dict( extent=[-1,21,-0.5,5.5], vmin=-1, vmax=6, origin="lower")
ax1.set_title("function evaluated on grid")
ax1.imshow(f(Xgrid, Ygrid), **kws)

ax2.set_title("interpolation using grid defined with np.meshgrid")
ax2.imshow(resampled.T, **kws)

ax3.set_title("interpolation using grid defined with np.mgrid")
ax3.imshow(resampled2.T, **kws)

for ax in (ax1, ax2, ax3):
    ax.set_yticks(range(6))
    ax.set_xticks(range(21)[::2])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

*Now to the question and its solution.*

#### Step 1. Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

(can be omitted, since more experienced users create those themselves when asking a question)

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.rand(532, 7)
dfList = [pd.DataFrame(a[:,i], columns=["Y"]) for i in range(7)]

# Meshgrid
xgrid = dfList[0].index.tolist()
ygrid = np.linspace(266, 1, 532)
Xgrid, Ygrid = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)

# Points
xo = dfList[0].index.tolist()
yo = [266, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 532]    # one for each DataFrame
points = [ [x, y] for y in yo for x in xo]
points = np.array(points)

# Values
values = []
for df in dfList:
    values.extend(df['Y'].real)

values = np.array(values)

# Griddata
resampled = scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, (Xgrid, Ygrid), method='cubic')

plt.imshow(resampled.T, extent=[365,1099,266,532], origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

creates

[image]

#### Step 2. The Problem.

We see a blank plot with only a small line of dots in the left handside of the image, while we would expect the complete graph to be filled with an image of shape `(266, 532)`.

#### Step 3. The solution.

Using `scipy.interpolate.griddata` we need to supply the grids to the `xi` argument as a tuple `(Xgrid.T, Ygrid.T)`, where the grids are generated via `numpy.meshgrid`: `Xgrid, Ygrid = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)`. Note that `meshgrid` is different from `numpy.mgrid`.

There are some other inconsistencies with the points of the meshgrid compared to the sample points, so here I assume that you want to have the values between 266 and 532 being interpolated.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.rand(532, 7)
dfList = [pd.DataFrame(a[:,i], columns=["Y"]) for i in range(7)]

# Meshgrid
xgrid = dfList[0].index.values
ygrid = np.arange(266,532)
Xgrid, Ygrid = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)

# Points
xo = dfList[0].index.tolist()
yo = [266, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 532]    # one for each DataFrame
points = [ [x, y] for y in yo for x in xo]
points = np.array(points)
print points.shape

# Values
values = []
for df in dfList:
    values.extend(df['Y'].real)
values = np.array(values)

# Griddata
resampled = scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, (Xgrid.T, Ygrid.T), method='cubic')
print resampled.T.shape
plt.imshow(resampled.T, extent=[365,1099,266,532], origin='lower') #, 

plt.show()
```

[image]